# Facebook comments box not showing

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

For some reason facebook comment box appears on my web articles only after I refresh the article page although it was working correctly few days ago:

The website is: http://metallica-gr.net/ , each article contains facebook comments on the bottom of the page.

Any ideas?

SOLUTION:

So I pasted the comments script right before closing  instead of right after openning it like it was recommended by Facebook and now it's working again. Not sure why that happened though since it was working fine, probably it conflicts with some other script?(although I didn't add anything to my website).

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the registration plugin http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13055336/anyone-having-issues-with-the-facebook-registration-plugin-today

Comment: So I suppose there is an issue with Facebook's end? Wouldn't more people know about it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I pasted the comments script right before closing `</body>` instead of right after openning it like it was recommended by Facebook and now it's working again. Not sure why that happened though since it was working fine, probably it conflicts with some other script?(although I didn't add anything to my website).

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery to show the facebook comment box:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    });
</script>
```