# facebook comments plugin showing only after refresh

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am trying to use the facebook comments plugin.

I have this code, I have added after the opening `<body>` tag and also tried before de closing `</body>` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055087/facebook-comments-box-not-showing)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID&version=v2.0";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
```

And on the 'show' page I have
 `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%=request.original_url %>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>`

The problem is that the plugin only shows when I refresh the page, not when I access the page through a link from the same site.

EDIT:

I discovered is has to do with turbolinks, I uninstalled it and it worked, I would like to find a solution with turbolinks installed. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066508/facebook-like-box-social-plugin-doesnt-work-with-turbolinks?lq=1) but couldn't make it work

Comment: Do you have any `Ad-blockers` or any other extensions in your browser? They might be preventing it.

Comment: Other sites load just fine, its mine that has the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. You need to turn off your turbolinks. Go the link where people are using to access the page and turn it off there. For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Use', model, class: "btn btn-primary", :"data-no-turbolink" => true %>
```

:"data-no-turbolink" => true

will do this for you. It's a known problem when combining JS with Rails.